# Asynchronous FIFO depth calculation

Tags: fpga, asic, soc, digital-design

I was required to calculate how long it will take to fill an asynchronous FIFO.
For example: Assume that module 'A' wants to send some data to the module 'B'.
The frequency of module A is 80MHz. The frequency of module B is 50MHz. The burst length is 120. There are no idle cycles in both reading and writing. The FIFO depth is 20. How long it will take to fill the FIFO?

I understand that the minimum depth of the FIFO should be 45.
'
Time required to write one data item=1/80MHz=12.5ns
Time required to write all the data in the burst=120*12.5ns=1500ns.
Time required to read one data item=1/50MHz=20ns.
The number of data item can be read in a duration of 1500ns=1500/20=75
The remaining number of bytes to be stored in FIFO =120-75=45.
But if the depth of FIFO is 20. How do I calculate the time to fill the FIFO?'

Question 2: I read some material. The depth of FIFO should be infinite if it is a continuous write. What is the difference between continuous and burst write? Why a finite depth of FIFO is enough for a burst to write?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are continously reading and writing on both sides.
For a theoretical perfect FIFO, just solve the equation:

```
80000000*x-50000000*x=20
30000000*x=20
x=20/30000000
x=0.667µs
```

However, real-world FIFOs have clock domain crossing synchronizers, which essentially reduces the usable FIFO depth by a few entries. Often 2~4 entries are unusable.
You need to examine your particular FIFO to know exactly how many clock cycles, and therefore FIFO depth, are lost due to clock domain crossing synchronization.

I have no idea what you mean by "burst" in this situation.

Comment: Thanks for tutoring. I am very confused about the equation. For example, 80000000*x-50000000*x=45. 30000000*=45.  x=45/30000000. x=1.5us. The equation means it will takes 1.5us to fill the FIFO. The results is conflict with expectation which is 45 depth FIFO will not be full.

Comment: The 45 entry FIFO will be full after 1.5us. (Actually a bit earlier, taking CDC synchronizers into acount)